# How to rank in a fourth column a combination of ids using a shared third column from lowest to highest?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, rank

edit: works with a modified version of the ticked answer like below

```
data1 <- data %>% group_by(pitch_2) %>% mutate(rank = order(euclid_dist))
```

original ----

I have in my dataframe a pairing of every possible pitch combination from my timeframe (over 80 million)--under pitch_1 is one id and under pitch_2 is another id with a third column euclid_dist a measure for how close one pitch is to another--and I would like to create a fourth column in my dataframe where I rank the combinations by lowest number (best match) to highest.

I want the ranking to be done relative to other combinations with the same primary pitch in pitch_2. So they're ranking the pitch under pitch_1 by lowest number first compared to all other pitch_1s that are being compared to the same pitch_2.

Here's just an idea of what my data looks like

```
> head(data)
    pitch_1   pitch_2 euclid_dist
2 400010-FF 493247-SI    3.631515
3 493247-SL 493247-SI    3.125729
4 349193-FT 493247-SI    4.619143
5 150037-FF 493247-SI    4.137001
6 218596-FF 493247-SI    2.536352
7 218596-SI 493247-SI    1.438356
```

using the rank on that small subset I got what I want my data to look like but don't know how to expand that to my big dataframe with who a whole number of pitch_2s

```
data$rank <-  rank(data$euclid_dist)
```

what I want it to look like (there are some rows you don't see that fill the other ranks)

```
    pitch_1   pitch_2 euclid_dist rank
2 400010-FF 493247-SI    3.631515    7
3 493247-SL 493247-SI    3.125729    6
4 349193-FT 493247-SI    4.619143   10
5 150037-FF 493247-SI    4.137001    8
6 218596-FF 493247-SI    2.536352    4
7 218596-SI 493247-SI    1.438356    1
```

Comment: rank(-data$euclid_dist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `dplyr` s mutate + order:

```
df <- data_frame(x = c(100, 300, 400, 50, 20, 600))

df <- df %>% mutate(xx = order(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this-

```
> library(data.table)
> setDT(dt)[,rank:=rank(euclid_dist)]
```

**Output-**

```
> dt
     pitch_1   pitch_2 euclid_dist rank
1: 400010-FF 493247-SI    3.631515    4
2: 493247-SL 493247-SI    3.125729    3
3: 349193-FT 493247-SI    4.619143    6
4: 150037-FF 493247-SI    4.137001    5
5: 218596-FF 493247-SI    2.536352    2
6: 218596-SI 493247-SI    1.438356    1
```

**Input**-

```
dt <- read.table(text=' pitch_1   pitch_2 euclid_dist
2 400010-FF 493247-SI    3.631515
3 493247-SL 493247-SI    3.125729
4 349193-FT 493247-SI    4.619143
5 150037-FF 493247-SI    4.137001
6 218596-FF 493247-SI    2.536352
7 218596-SI 493247-SI    1.438356',header=T)
```